Is it possible to log different levels into console vs log file?
Is it possible to create a launch file so that I only see INFO and about on the console, but all DEBUG messages go into the log file? Thanks!

No, that is not possible.
As it is currently implemented, the loglevel dictates whether the log handler is called or not, and the log handler deals with outputting the log message.
But there is no per-handler loglevel.
For more in-depth info, see here.
